# Cloudfront Brotli Compression Not Working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a javascript file hosted on Cloudfront, the 'Compress objects automatically' settings are set to Yes in the distribution settings. When I request this javascript file, I always get the gzipped version even though my browser accept-encoding is set to: `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`.

How can I fix this to get Cloudfront to return the Brotli version whenever the browser supports it instead of always sending the gzipped version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is stored on S3 uncompressed, and Gzip compression is working, one setting to check is whether the Cache Policy that you have attached to this cache behavior has Brotli compression enabled. You have to enable Brotli and Gzip compression separately.

Comment: The file is stored uncompressed, it's a javascript file and it currently return only the Gzipped version even when the browser supports Brotli.

Comment: Even if the browser supports Brotli, CloudFront needs to be configured to compress to Brotli. The TTLs in your cache policy also need to be > 0. Did you check the cache policy settings that I mentioned above? See here for details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

Comment: Yes, the TTL is set to 1 and the cache policy is configured to compress Brotli and Gzipped. I also noticed that it works for files with the .json extension but not the file in the .js extension, they are in different folders.

Comment: Are both files mapping to the same cache behavior (route)? If so, other possibilities are the file is not between 1K and 10MM bytes in size, or the content-type isn't set correctly (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types). The link above has details about all the scenarios where CloudFront will and won't compress content.

Comment: I'm seeing all of my files served as gzip as well. If I disable gzip but keep brotli enabled and invalidate the cache, it will serve brotli (level 5 compression). I am unable to get cloudfront to serve brotli when gzip is also enabled. It seems to favor gzip no matter what.